# TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm having problem using  {% url %} tag in django template.

```
<a href="{% url baza.views.thread category.last_post.thread.pk %}">LINK</a>
```

Throwing this error:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'baza.views.thread' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

What's weird, it works used like this:

```
{{ category.last_post.thread.pk }}
```

returns correct value which is '8', also doesn't throw error when I'm using it like this:

```
<a href="{% url baza.views.thread 8 %}">LINK</a>
```

Above code works fine, and redirects to thread.

my urls.py :

```
...
(r"^temat/(\d+)/$", "thread"),
...
```

post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
```

thread view:

```
def thread(request, pk):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(thread=pk).order_by("created")
    posts = mk_paginator(request, posts, 20) # ZMIEN TAKZE W get_thread_page
    t = Thread.objects.get(pk=pk)

    return render_to_response("baza/thread.html", add_csrf(request, posts=posts, pk=pk, title=t.title,
    element_pk=t.element.pk, media_url=MEDIA_URL, path = request.path))
```

category model has "last_post" metod which returns last msg posted in this category.

Could someone help me with this annoying problem?

Regards.

Ps. I'm using Django Version: 1.3.1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the value of the next expression `category.last_post.thread.pk` is None or ''. And no *Reverse for 'baza.views.thread' with **arguments** '(**''**,)'*.

Arguments ('',) implies that `category.last_post.thread.pk` is None or ''

Comment: but why it does work with {{ category.last_post.thread.pk }} and returns value of 8 which is true for my case?

Comment: If you code this line  {{ category.last_post.thread.pk }} instead of this line <a href="{% url baza.views.thread category.last_post.thread.pk %}">LINK</a>. does it return 8, sure?

Comment: Then change the urls.py Something like this: (r"^temat/(?P<pk>\d+)/$", "thread"), or even (r"^temat/(?P<pk>\w+)/$", "thread"),

Comment: For me this no sense... I test the last thing (only to try understand it): In the template: {% url baza.views.thread %} and in the urls (r"^temat/$", "thread"), and in the views def thread(request, pk=None). This does not work, only is a test

Comment: One point for your question, I think that this is the moment to a bounty